# How to stop msbuild from generating map file

Tags: delphi, msbuild

Using windows 10, delphi 11.2, msbuild 4.8.4084.0. I have a set of scripts to rebuild all projects. Currently, it invokes msbuild like so:

```
msbuild  /v:q  /p:config=Release /p:platform=Win32 /t:rebuild  someproject.dproj
```

And whether a map file is created seems to depend (as it should) on settings within the dproj file - more or less. (Delphi seems to treat mapfile=off as the default if its absent, whereas msbuild seems to treat "Detailed" as the default).

In an attempt to suppress the map file, I've tried using this msbuild command:

```
msbuild  /v:q  /p:config=Release /p:platform=Win32 /p:DCC_MapFile=0 /t:rebuild  someproject.dproj
```

This results in a map file being generated that matches the detailed map file in size. The msbuild command does respond to the extra parameter sometimes though. e.g. DCC_MapFile=1 will generate a very small map file. But any other value (0, 2, 3) and you get the large map file.

Comment: DCC_MapFile=0 does not create a map file on my side, even if the Release configuration in the .dproj has MapFile set to Detailed.
I'm using a bit older msbuild though - Microsoft (R) Build Engine version 4.8.3761.0

Comment: @dwrbudr Thanks for that. Interesting. That is exactly the behaviour I want (and expect).